# I have a match in codeigniter but I need to order by best match

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, match

Hello I have this code and it works but the match does not return the array ordered by best match. How can I order that array by similar to $search.

```
        $this->db->select("p.code, p.STOCK, t.TITLE, p.UNIFICADO, p.BRAND, p.DESCRIPTION, p.PRECIO, p.DEPENDENCIA");
        $this->db->from('part_info_titles t');
        $this->db->join('part_info p', 't.INTERNAL_CODE = p.NKR_CODE');
        $this->db->join('application a', 'p.UNIFICADO = a.UNIFICADO');
        $this->db->where("a.FROM_YEAR <=",$year);
        $this->db->where("a.THRU_YEAR >=",$year);
        $this->db->where("a.MODEL", $model);
        if(($engine != "all")and($engine != 'ALL')){
        $engines = array($engine, 'ALL', 'all','');
        $this->db->where_in('a.ENGINE', $engines);
        }
        $this->db->group_by('p.code'); 
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->where('MATCH (t.TITLE) AGAINST ("'.$search.'")', NULL, false);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
```

thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution tested with your sample data:

```
    $search = 'door mirror';
    $year = 2000;
    $model = 'NPR';
    $engine = 'all';

    $this->db->select('p.NKR_CODE, p.STOCK, t.TITLE, p.UNIFICADO, p.BRAND, p.DESCRIPTION, p.PRECIO, p.DEPENDENCIA, 
       MATCH (t.TITLE) AGAINST ("'.$search.'") AS relevance', FALSE);
    $this->db->from('part_info_titles t');
    $this->db->join('part_info p', 't.INTERNAL_CODE = p.NKR_CODE');
    $this->db->join('application a', 'p.UNIFICADO = a.UNIFICADO');
    $this->db->where("a.FROM_YEAR <=",$year);
    $this->db->where("a.THRU_YEAR >=",$year);
    $this->db->where("a.MODEL", $model);
    if(($engine != "all") and ($engine != 'ALL')){
       $engines = array($engine, 'ALL', 'all','');
       $this->db->where_in('a.ENGINE', $engines);
    }

    $this->db->where('MATCH (t.TITLE) AGAINST ("'.$search.'")', NULL, false);       

    $this->db->group_by('p.NKR_CODE'); 

    // ORDER BY RELEVANCE IN DESCENDING ORDER
    $this->db->order_by("relevance", "desc");

    $query = $this->db->get();

    // CHECK TO SE IF ANY DATA EXISTS BEFORE RETURNING...
    if($query !== FALSE && $query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

And in Pure SQL if needed:

```
SELECT p.NKR_CODE, p.STOCK, t.TITLE, p.UNIFICADO, p.BRAND, p.DESCRIPTION, p.PRECIO, p.DEPENDENCIA, 
       MATCH (t.TITLE) AGAINST ('door mirror') AS relevance
FROM part_info_titles t
INNER JOIN part_info p ON t.INTERNAL_CODE = p.NKR_CODE
INNER JOIN application a ON p.UNIFICADO = a.UNIFICADO
WHERE 
    a.FROM_YEAR <= 2000
    AND a.THRU_YEAR >= 2000
    AND a.MODEL = 'NPR'
#AND a.ENGINE IN('', 'ALL', 'all')
AND MATCH (t.TITLE) AGAINST ('door mirror')
GROUP BY p.NKR_CODE
ORDER BY relevance DESC;
```

Note: The sample data you provided only had one match in `t.INTERNAL_CODE = p.NKR_CODE` so only one row was returned.

Comment: it gives me Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on boolean

Comment: And no fatal error if the line `$this->db->order_by(`...  is removed?

Comment: yes without that line it works but the order is not right.

Comment: Strange... the error usually occur when no data are found.. Updated example with a check if any rows are returned...

Comment: Try select `MATCH (`... as `relevance` and then order by relevance. Updated my answer. Does this work?

Comment: when I add the order_by("relevance", "desc") or select MATCH (... as relevance it does not return anything.
I tried to make var_dump($query) and it return "bool(false)"

Comment: Did you add the `, FALSE);` at the end in the select-statement... Just updated the answer again. You May also try paranthesis around the match `(MATCH (t.TITLE) AGAINST ("'.$search.'")) AS relevance', FALSE);`

Comment: I have tried everything, is just find text in a description
$this->db->select("p.NKR_CODE, p.STOCK, t.TITLE, p.UNIFICADO, p.BRAND, p.DESCRIPTION, p.PRECIO, p.DEPENDENCIA
   (MATCH (t.TITLE) AGAINST ('door mirror'), NULL, false)");

Comment: Forgot a comma, should be: `p.DEPENDENCIA, (MATCH (t.TITLE) AGAINST ('door mirror')) AS relevance', NULL, false);` You also need to keep the where clause with the match...

Comment: I have tried everything, is just find text in a description and I don't know what to do. 

$this->db->select("p.NKR_CODE, p.STOCK, t.TITLE, p.UNIFICADO, p.BRAND, p.DESCRIPTION, p.PRECIO, p.DEPENDENCIA
   (MATCH (t.TITLE) AGAINST ('door mirror'), NULL, false)");
I tried this too, only to know if it the match works inside the select and it show the same error.

Comment: yes I tried with the comma too and nothing. I am not able to add the match inside the select with success

Comment: OK, I will try replicate.. Please update your question with MySQL-version, and if its MyISAM or InnoDB tables? And which columns you have a fulltext index on. Only the title? I'll get back later with a working example..

Comment: MyISAM and 5.6.24 thank you so much for your help.. I can send you the table if you want... I have weeks trying to fix that.

Comment: Yes, that would help, its a lot of tables. You could create the table schemas and data on rextester: http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler or send me the table

Comment: link to chat. [chat](https://secure.livechatinc.com/licence/8139451/open_chat.cgi?groups=1?web=justautomotivepart.com)

Comment: In your sample data you only had one `NKR_CODE` matching with `INTERNAL_CODE`, but I have now tested the solution and it should work. Updated the answer..

Comment: That is perfect thank you so much! it is awesome!... I really appreciate the effort you have made to help me.

Comment: It is not working for some search like this one [picture](http://take.ms/KnCOo) I don't know why the fan clutch is not at the first row... when I change the order to ASC one of the fan clutch is the last one. maybe the var type?

Comment: You can fine tune the relevance calculation in different ways.. if you provide the data from your example, I can give it a try. Also, if the calculated relevance are same for multiple matches you may want to order by relevance first, then title: `$this->db->order_by("relevance DESC, t.TITLE ASC");`